# A compressed folder cannot be extracted by tarfile

Tags: python, tar

For a build script written in python, I would need to extract the contents of a `.tar.gz` archive ([this is Lua's source](https://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.5.tar.gz)).

In the [`tarfile` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html), [an archive with such an extension](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#examples) can be extracted this way, I replaced their example file with the archive I want to extract:

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("lua-5.3.5.tar.gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Python nevertheless returns an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    tar = tarfile.open("lua-5.3.5.tar.gz")
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tarfile.py", line 1578, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

Of course I run this script in the same folder as the archive, yet it can't extract the content.

How do we solve this problem?

Comment: Despite the answers posted here so far, the code you're trying to use should work just fine without modification (at least, using `tarfile` with Python 3.7 I can open  and extract a `.tar.gz` without any additional parameters). Can you point us at the specific tarfile you're trying to unpack? And have you verified that it works correctly when using the `tar` cli?

Comment: Yes, it is. I posted a reply, the reinstallation of the Python environment seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that after a reinstall of the Python environment (nothing ventured, nothing gained), it worked. It frustrates me a bit not to understand what caused the error, most likely corrupted files, yet I often update my packages, it's weird.

Answer (score -1):

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("lua-5.3.5.tar.gz", "w|gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The exception no longer appears, however, no files seem to be extracted, the archive, on the other hand, seems to be overwrote by a new empty archive. Do you have any idea how to fix this? By searching in the documentation and on the internet, the code you wrote should match the expectations, but apparently it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.

Answer (score -2):

That file is actually a `tar.gz` file, therefore you must do something like this:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("lua-5.3.5.tar.gz", "r:gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Comment: `fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')`

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lua-5.3.5.tar.gz'`